# How to auto-import declarations.d.ts in vite/unplugin-auto-import?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to auto-import `src/declarations.d.ts` into my vue components but can't get it to work. This is my `vite.config.ts`:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import Pages from 'vite-plugin-pages'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    Pages(),
    AutoImport({
      // targets to transform
      include: [
        /\.[tj]sx?$/, // .ts, .tsx, .js, .jsx
        /\.vue$/, /\.vue\?vue/, // .vue
        /\.md$/, // .md
      ],

      // global imports to register
      imports: [
        // presets
        'vue',
        'vue-router',
        // custom
        {
          'declarations': [],
          '@vueuse/core': [
            // named imports
            'onClickOutside', 'useToggle', 'useDark', 'useElementSize', // import { onClickOutside } from '@vueuse/core',
            // alias
            ['useFetch', 'useMyFetch'], // import { useFetch as useMyFetch } from '@vueuse/core',
          ],
          'axios': [
            // default imports
            ['default', 'axios'], // import { default as axios } from 'axios',
          ],
          '[package-name]': [
            '[import-names]',
            // alias
            ['[from]', '[alias]'],
          ],
        },
      ],
      // Enable auto import by filename for default module exports under directories
      defaultExportByFilename: false,

      // Auto import for module exports under directories
      // by default it only scan one level of modules under the directory
      dirs: [
        './src/lib',
        // './hooks',
        // './composables/**', // all nested modules
        // ...
      ],

      // Filepath to generate corresponding .d.ts file.
      // Defaults to './auto-imports.d.ts' when `typescript` is installed locally.
      // Set `false` to disable.
      dts: './auto-imports.d.ts',

      // Auto import inside Vue template
      // see https://github.com/unjs/unimport/pull/15 and https://github.com/unjs/unimport/pull/72
      vueTemplate: true,

      // Custom resolvers, compatible with `unplugin-vue-components`
      // see https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-auto-import/pull/23/
      resolvers: [
        /* ... */
      ],

      // Generate corresponding .eslintrc-auto-import.json file.
      // eslint globals Docs - https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-globals
      eslintrc: {
        enabled: false, // Default `false`
        filepath: './.eslintrc-auto-import.json', // Default `./.eslintrc-auto-import.json`
        globalsPropValue: true, // Default `true`, (true | false | 'readonly' | 'readable' | 'writable' | 'writeable')
      },
    }),
    Components({
      dirs: ['src', 'node_modules']
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  }
})
```

I've tried adding it into `global imports` but no effect.

**Edit:**

`auto-imports.d.ts`:

```
/* eslint-disable */
/* prettier-ignore */
// @ts-nocheck
// Generated by unplugin-auto-import
export {}
declare global {
  const EffectScope: typeof import('vue')['EffectScope']
  const [alias]: typeof import('[package-name]')['[from]']
  const [import-names]: typeof import('[package-name]')['[import-names]']
  const axios: typeof import('axios')['default']
  const computed: typeof import('vue')['computed']
  const createApp: typeof import('vue')['createApp']
  const customRef: typeof import('vue')['customRef']
  const defineAsyncComponent: typeof import('vue')['defineAsyncComponent']
  const defineComponent: typeof import('vue')['defineComponent']
  const effectScope: typeof import('vue')['effectScope']
  const getCurrentInstance: typeof import('vue')['getCurrentInstance']
  const getCurrentScope: typeof import('vue')['getCurrentScope']
  const h: typeof import('vue')['h']
  const inject: typeof import('vue')['inject']
  const isProxy: typeof import('vue')['isProxy']
  const isReactive: typeof import('vue')['isReactive']
  const isReadonly: typeof import('vue')['isReadonly']
  const isRef: typeof import('vue')['isRef']
  const markRaw: typeof import('vue')['markRaw']
  const nextTick: typeof import('vue')['nextTick']
  const onActivated: typeof import('vue')['onActivated']
  const onBeforeMount: typeof import('vue')['onBeforeMount']
  const onBeforeRouteLeave: typeof import('vue-router')['onBeforeRouteLeave']
  const onBeforeRouteUpdate: typeof import('vue-router')['onBeforeRouteUpdate']
  const onBeforeUnmount: typeof import('vue')['onBeforeUnmount']
  const onBeforeUpdate: typeof import('vue')['onBeforeUpdate']
  const onClickOutside: typeof import('@vueuse/core')['onClickOutside']
  const onDeactivated: typeof import('vue')['onDeactivated']
  const onErrorCaptured: typeof import('vue')['onErrorCaptured']
  const onMounted: typeof import('vue')['onMounted']
  const onRenderTracked: typeof import('vue')['onRenderTracked']
  const onRenderTriggered: typeof import('vue')['onRenderTriggered']
  const onScopeDispose: typeof import('vue')['onScopeDispose']
  const onServerPrefetch: typeof import('vue')['onServerPrefetch']
  const onUnmounted: typeof import('vue')['onUnmounted']
  const onUpdated: typeof import('vue')['onUpdated']
  const provide: typeof import('vue')['provide']
  const reactive: typeof import('vue')['reactive']
  const readonly: typeof import('vue')['readonly']
  const ref: typeof import('vue')['ref']
  const resolveComponent: typeof import('vue')['resolveComponent']
  const router: typeof import('./src/lib/router')['default']
  const shallowReactive: typeof import('vue')['shallowReactive']
  const shallowReadonly: typeof import('vue')['shallowReadonly']
  const shallowRef: typeof import('vue')['shallowRef']
  const store: typeof import('./src/lib/store')['store']
  const tiptapNodeExtension: typeof import('./src/lib/tiptap-node-extension')['default']
  const toRaw: typeof import('vue')['toRaw']
  const toRef: typeof import('vue')['toRef']
  const toRefs: typeof import('vue')['toRefs']
  const triggerRef: typeof import('vue')['triggerRef']
  const unref: typeof import('vue')['unref']
  const useAttrs: typeof import('vue')['useAttrs']
  const useCssModule: typeof import('vue')['useCssModule']
  const useCssVars: typeof import('vue')['useCssVars']
  const useDark: typeof import('@vueuse/core')['useDark']
  const useElementSize: typeof import('@vueuse/core')['useElementSize']
  const useLink: typeof import('vue-router')['useLink']
  const useMyFetch: typeof import('@vueuse/core')['useFetch']
  const useRoute: typeof import('vue-router')['useRoute']
  const useRouter: typeof import('vue-router')['useRouter']
  const useSlots: typeof import('vue')['useSlots']
  const useToggle: typeof import('@vueuse/core')['useToggle']
  const watch: typeof import('vue')['watch']
  const watchEffect: typeof import('vue')['watchEffect']
  const watchPostEffect: typeof import('vue')['watchPostEffect']
  const watchSyncEffect: typeof import('vue')['watchSyncEffect']
}
// for type re-export
declare global {
  // @ts-ignore
  export type { Component, ComponentPublicInstance, ComputedRef, InjectionKey, PropType, Ref, VNode } from 'vue'
}
// for vue template auto import
import { UnwrapRef } from 'vue'
declare module 'vue' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    readonly EffectScope: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['EffectScope']>
    readonly [alias]: UnwrapRef<typeof import('[package-name]')['[from]']>
    readonly [import-names]: UnwrapRef<typeof import('[package-name]')['[import-names]']>
    readonly axios: UnwrapRef<typeof import('axios')['default']>
    readonly computed: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['computed']>
    readonly createApp: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['createApp']>
    readonly customRef: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['customRef']>
    readonly defineAsyncComponent: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['defineAsyncComponent']>
    readonly defineComponent: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['defineComponent']>
    readonly effectScope: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['effectScope']>
    readonly getCurrentInstance: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['getCurrentInstance']>
    readonly getCurrentScope: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['getCurrentScope']>
    readonly h: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['h']>
    readonly inject: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['inject']>
    readonly isProxy: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['isProxy']>
    readonly isReactive: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['isReactive']>
    readonly isReadonly: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['isReadonly']>
    readonly isRef: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['isRef']>
    readonly markRaw: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['markRaw']>
    readonly nextTick: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['nextTick']>
    readonly onActivated: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['onActivated']>
    readonly onBeforeMount: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['onBeforeMount']>
    readonly onBeforeRouteLeave: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue-router')['onBeforeRouteLeave']>
    readonly onBeforeRouteUpdate: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue-router')['onBeforeRouteUpdate']>
    readonly onBeforeUnmount: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['onBeforeUnmount']>
    readonly onBeforeUpdate: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['onBeforeUpdate']>
    readonly onClickOutside: UnwrapRef<typeof import('@vueuse/core')['onClickOutside']>
    readonly onDeactivated: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['onDeactivated']>
    readonly onErrorCaptured: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['onErrorCaptured']>
    readonly onMounted: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['onMounted']>
    readonly onRenderTracked: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['onRenderTracked']>
    readonly onRenderTriggered: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['onRenderTriggered']>
    readonly onScopeDispose: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['onScopeDispose']>
    readonly onServerPrefetch: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['onServerPrefetch']>
    readonly onUnmounted: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['onUnmounted']>
    readonly onUpdated: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['onUpdated']>
    readonly provide: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['provide']>
    readonly reactive: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['reactive']>
    readonly readonly: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['readonly']>
    readonly ref: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['ref']>
    readonly resolveComponent: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['resolveComponent']>
    readonly router: UnwrapRef<typeof import('./src/lib/router')['default']>
    readonly shallowReactive: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['shallowReactive']>
    readonly shallowReadonly: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['shallowReadonly']>
    readonly shallowRef: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['shallowRef']>
    readonly store: UnwrapRef<typeof import('./src/lib/store')['store']>
    readonly tiptapNodeExtension: UnwrapRef<typeof import('./src/lib/tiptap-node-extension')['default']>
    readonly toRaw: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['toRaw']>
    readonly toRef: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['toRef']>
    readonly toRefs: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['toRefs']>
    readonly triggerRef: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['triggerRef']>
    readonly unref: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['unref']>
    readonly useAttrs: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['useAttrs']>
    readonly useCssModule: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['useCssModule']>
    readonly useCssVars: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['useCssVars']>
    readonly useDark: UnwrapRef<typeof import('@vueuse/core')['useDark']>
    readonly useElementSize: UnwrapRef<typeof import('@vueuse/core')['useElementSize']>
    readonly useLink: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue-router')['useLink']>
    readonly useMyFetch: UnwrapRef<typeof import('@vueuse/core')['useFetch']>
    readonly useRoute: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue-router')['useRoute']>
    readonly useRouter: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue-router')['useRouter']>
    readonly useSlots: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['useSlots']>
    readonly useToggle: UnwrapRef<typeof import('@vueuse/core')['useToggle']>
    readonly watch: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['watch']>
    readonly watchEffect: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['watchEffect']>
    readonly watchPostEffect: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['watchPostEffect']>
    readonly watchSyncEffect: UnwrapRef<typeof import('vue')['watchSyncEffect']>
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the contents of `auto-imports.d.ts`?

Comment: Did you solve this issue somehow?

Comment: @quippe Yes, I dumped typescript from my project. On a more serious note, no, I have to manually import type declarations into my components (which was one reason for dumping it).

Answer (score 0):

I follow everything that document say and still get "not found" problem.

After I add

```
auto-imports.d.ts
```

on *tsconfig.app.json* and It Work!!

```
// tsconfig.app.json
{
 "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
 "include": [
   "env.d.ts",
   ...
   "auto-imports.d.ts" // add this line
 ],
 ...
}
```